# How to append only a div from ajax().done()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem when using the following javascript. When pressing the #search_room_button, it will run and replace the #matched_rooms div with a copy of the whole website. However, I wish only to have the new #matched_rooms div returned and thereby replacing the old one. How can this be done?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#search_room_button").on('click', function() {

            $("#matched_rooms").html("<p>LOADING</p>");

            $.ajax({
                url: 'book.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    'rtid': 1,
                    'date': $("#date").val(),
                    'time': $(".ui_tpicker_time").text(),
                    'duration': 4
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                $("#matched_rooms").html(data, "#matched_rooms");
            })
        })
    });


</script>
```

Comment: `html` method doesn't accept 2 parameters.

Comment: [`.html()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't have a second parameter?

Comment: @undefined you're pretty smart for an `undefined`.

Comment: You have to do a find on data first. I'll post some code soon.

Comment: Return the HTML you want in book.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you should be using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead of `.get()` - it has built-in functionality for replacing an existing node's contents with the *partial* contents of an AJAX request.

Just be careful with your DOM structure - jQuery expects to replace the entire *contents* of the original element with the specified element itself, not the specified element's contents.

You should wrap your `#matched_rooms` element in a `#container` element, and then use that:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="matched_rooms"> ... </div>
</div>
```

with code:

```
$("#matched_rooms").html("<p>LOADING</p>");
$('#container').load('book.php #matched_rooms', { // NB: selector parameter!
    'rtid': 1,
    'date': $("#date").val(),
    'time': $(".ui_tpicker_time").text(),
    'duration': 4
});
```

There's no need for a success handler - the insertion back into the DOM is automatic.

Comment: Except for the fact that I used a get request and this seems to send a post request everything now works fine. Easy fix: convert the $_GETs to $_POST :)Thanks for your help!

Comment: According to the docs, jQuery uses `POST` if you supply a data object, or `GET` otherwise.  I presume that serialising the data yourself and adding it to the URL would do that too.  You could of course use `$_REQUEST` in your PHP which will work with either.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for

```
$("#matched_rooms").html($(data).find("#matched_rooms").html());
```

Btw, there's also a (limited) shortcut for this functionality: [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$("#matched_rooms")
  .html("<p>LOADING</p>")
  .parent().load('book.php #matched_rooms', {
    'rtid': 1,
    'date': $("#date").val(),
    'time': $(".ui_tpicker_time").text(),
    'duration': 4
  });
```

Comment: same comment as for the other answer - using `.load` like this will result in multiple incorrectly nested elements with the `#matched_rooms` id.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, fixed now.

Comment: Yup, so long as `#matched_rooms` has no siblings.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead of `$.ajax`.

```
$('#surrounding_element').load('book.php #matched_rooms', {
                'rtid': 1,
                'date': $("#date").val(),
                'time': $(".ui_tpicker_time").text(),
                'duration': 4
});
```

Where you should update Your html code with for example:

```
<span id="surrounding_element">
    <div id="matched_rooms"></div>
</span>
```

Comment: this will result in a double-nested `#matched_rooms` structure.

Comment: and now your answer looks identical to mine... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try: `$("#matched_rooms").html(data.find('#matched_rooms').html());`

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you mean, but maybe something like this:
`$("#matched_rooms").html($(data).find("#matched_rooms"));`

(I made the assumption the data returned by the ajax request returns the whole page)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of your `data` html this should help:

```
var newHtml = $('#matched_rooms', data);
$("#matched_rooms").html(newHtml);
```

You /may/ need to use `filter` depending on your HTML structure

Answer (score 0):

This is what could be done:

```
get.done(function(data) { 
                var message1 = $(data).find('#message1');
                var message2 = $(data).find('#message2');
                var NewList = $(data).find('div');
                $('#error').html(message1.html());
                $('#results').html(message2.html());
```

**This is an example not copy and paste code **